# Display right 0,5cm dead, how to set custom screen boundaries?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I just dropped my MBP (dumb dumb me) and about 0,5cm on the right side of the screen are dead. I don't want to afford the 500-600$ to get a replacement and since it's just a black bar on the right, I can ignore it.
How can I tell macOS to also ignore it? right now, some buttons are hidden beneath it, and I never really remembered which they are.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235115/only-half-of-the-display-works-can-i-set-to-display-only-in-that-region (I'm sure there are other questions on here too, I just can't find them yet) Basically, there's no real way to do this.